# compiler error on including a custom made header file

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Good evening,

Some of you might consider this as a stupid question. But I've started learning C++ and everything was going fine until I've ran into this error which has been buging me for days. I've done some research on web and fixed everything i could so far.

The problem is that when i try to include a new header file that I've made the compiler does not recognize the content of that file. I'm using Dev-C++ compiler.

when i try to compile i get the following error: main.cpp line 8 error: `test123' undeclared (first use this function)

I have a folder named 001 in which i have another folder named src (where i store my .h files), and main.cpp and new.cpp .

Here's the code of main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "src/functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    test123(5,'Test String');

    //close on enter keystroke
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(255,'\n');
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the code in functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

    string test123(int i,string inputStr);

#endif
```

heres the code in functions.cpp:

```
#include "src/functions.h"

string test123(int n, inputStr){
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        cout << "\n\t"+inputStr <<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error: `test123' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: Is that your real code? I don't see how functions.cpp could possibly compile.

Answer (score 2):

1. In header, variable must be declared as `extern` and then defined in `.cpp` file.
2. `functions.h` does not have `#include <string>` to provide the return type of function `test123`
3. .cpp file does not have `#include <iostream>` to provide `cout`.
4. You have no type for `inputStr` argument for `test123` definition in functions.cpp.

   ```
   #ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
   #define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

   #include <string>

   extern int testVar;
   std::string test123(int i, std::string inputStr);

   #endif
   ```

   And for .cpp:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "src/functions.h"

   using namespace std;

   int testVar = 123456;

   string test123(int n, string inputStr){
       for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
           cout << "\n\t"+inputStr <<endl;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i removed the variable, added the '#include <string>' and 'using namespace std;' but i continue getting the error.

Comment: I don't recommend `using namespace std;`, and certainly don't use it in a header file.

Comment: @FredLarson I didn't want to change the source. Indeed, it's better to fix it.

Comment: @user3111896 too many errors in your source, now it looks fixed.

Comment: ok, first of all I'm sorry for bothering you with this but I keep running into problems. I've changed line 8 in main.cpp to     //test123(5,'Test String'); . Now its just testVar left, and when i try to compile i get this error:    [Linker error] undefined reference to `testVar' . I've allready reread the book chapter several times to see if i find any mistakes but everything seems to be just fine.

Comment: @user3111896 delete line `extern int testVar` from header. Edit: if you declares variable in header, it will have external linkage, so you must define it to avoid linker errors.

Comment: ok, now i've managed to compile but the testVar is getting value of 0.

Comment: @user3111896 If you don't change it anywhere, it _must_ have the same value as you defined in .cpp file. Check functions.cpp and usage of this variable.

Comment: Ok, after taking a small break and rethinking everything again I've managed it to run. Thank you for your patience.I realy apreciate your help and patience. I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 0):

`functions.cpp` doesn't include the definitions of the `string` type returned by `test123`; the second argument of `test123` has no type whatsoever. This can't possibly compile. The compiler might just discard the completely screwed up definition of `test123`, and thus confused complain later. But the problem is the incorrect declaration, and I'd be extremely surprised if the compiler doesn't complain loudly about it before.

If you want some clarification here, it is commendable to try to reduce the problem to as small a program showing the problem as you possibly can, nobody wades for fun through hundreds of irrelevant lines of a program they really don't care about. But please make sure the result *does* compile, or nearly so, and *does* show the exact problem you want advise on. Make sure any compiler messages that mystify you are the *only* ones.

Comment: @user3111896, "fixing" a program by random changes won't get you far, that is all I'll say.